# Probability Unfair Coins

Tags: probability

I have two coins, yielding heads at $P(H) = a$ and the other with $P(H) = b$.
Is it possible for the following to be equal? If so, what should be values for $a$ and $b$?

(a) $p_1$=neither is head

(b) $p_2$=exactly one of the coins is a head

(c) $p_3$=both are heads

I am not sure where I am going with this. I am thinking that:

$p_1= (1-a)(1-b)$,

$p_2=a(1-b)+b(1-a)$

$p_3=ab$

Is this correct? In addition, I see the coins as definitely unfair, but should they be double headed/tailed?

I found: 
$p_1=p_3 \iff a+b=1$

Is it safe to describe the possible values of $a$ and $b$ as complements?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  I expect the downvotes (not from me) are because you don't show any effort.  This isn't a homework site, and people like to see that you've tried to solve the problem.  So...what have you tried?  Where did you get stuck?  Surely, for example, you can compute some of the requisite probabilities?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment.

Comment: I am not sure where I am going with this. I am thinking that the p1= (1-a)∩(1-b) p2=a∪b and p3=a∩b. Is this correct?

Comment: Your logic is sound, but $a$ and $b$ are numbers...not sets.  So where you have $\cap$ you ought to have product.

Comment: Note:  I think that $p_2$ is poorly defined.  Does it mean the probability that exactly one of them is Heads or that at least one of them is Heads?  Given $p_1,p_3$ I expect they mean "exactly" but it isn't clear as written.

Comment: I see, thank you. For the value of p2, can I see it as it equaling either a or b?

Comment: If we take it to mean "exactly"  then we need EITHER the first coin in Heads and the second Tails, or the other way round.  Thus $p_2=a(1-b)+b(1-a)$.  If it means "at least"  then $p_2=1-p_1$.  But I am fairly sure it means "exactly".

Comment: Can you explain why p2=a(1−b)+b(1−a) please?

Comment: Yes.  We consider two mutually exclusive events $E_1$ is the event that the $a-$coin is $H$ AND the $b$-coin is $T$, while $E_2$ is the event that the $b-$coin is $H$ AND the $a$-coin is $T$.  Trusting that the coin tosses are independent (which you didn't say, but surely you intended) $P(E_1)=a(1-b)$ as it is the product of the probabilities that the $a-$ coin is $H$ and the $b-$ coin is $T$.  Similarly for $P(E_2)$.

Comment: Surely you've worked this sort of thing out for fair coins, no?  If not, set this problem aside and go work that case out carefully.  Then try it with $a=.6$ and $b=.75$, just as an example (nothing special about those numbers).

Comment: OK. Will do. Thank you for your help. I will go try out the other cases.

Comment: Using the 3 different p1, p2, and p3 as a system of equations, I can't find values for a or b that will work. But, something tells me that all three probabilities could be equal somehow.

Comment: Please edit your post to show your calculation.  By the way, what you wrote is correct...$p_1=p_3\iff a+b=1$

Comment: Done. Sounds good. Thank you.

Comment: Well, it doesn't look like you are finished.  You still have to deal with $p_2$.  Figuring they meant "exactly" one, $p_2=-2ab+a+b=-2ab+1$ (assuming $p_1=p_3$).  But then we see that $p_2=p_3\implies -2ab=ab\implies ab=\frac 13$.  So now you want $a+b=1$ AND $ab=\frac 13$.  Can you solve that system?

Comment: Correction (to my comment):  there's a typo.  I meant to write $p_2=p_3\implies -2ab+1=ab\implies ab=\frac 13$.

Answer (score 1):

"I am not sure where I am going with this. I am thinking that the p1= (1-a)(1-b) p2=a∪b and p3=ab."

p1 and p2 are correct.  "p2=a∪b" is nonsense because p2 is a number, not a set.  You have already said that the probability that both are heads (p1) is (1- a)(1- b) and that the probability neither is heads (p2) is ab.  The only thing left is "one is heads and the other isn't" or "exactly one is heads".  So the probability of that is 1- (1- a)(1- b)- ab= 1- 1+ a+ b- ab- ab= a+ b- 2ab.

"In addition, I see the coins as definitely unfair, but should they be double headed/tailed?"

If you think that the only way coins can be unfair is to be "double headed" or "double tailed" you are very unimaginative. (Or haven't spent enough time flipping coins!) It is not at all difficult to weight coins or grind down their edges so that the are more likely to come up one rather than the other.

Comment: Oddly, it turns out that it isn't real easy to make a loaded coin.  Not if you are just going to toss it (if you spin it and let it fall, then you can).  [Here's](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/diceRev2.pdf) a relevant article.  (clearly not relevant to the OP's question, but maybe interesting?)

Answer (score 0):

To satisfy (a),(b) and (c) you need first (a)=(c), which as you say, means

$$a+b=1$$

This also means that $1-2ab=ab$ (from (b)=(c)), so $ab=\frac 13$.
Substitute $a=1-b$, we get $b(1-b)=\frac 13$.

However $b(1-b)$ has a local maxima at $b=\frac 12$, and this equates to $\frac 14$, meaning that no real solution is possible.